# Is there a quick way to check if ANY column is NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with around 20 columns.  Aside from typing out:

```
Where column1 is null OR column2 is null OR column3 is null etc...
```

Is there a quicker way to just check every column and see if any value is null and if so, return that record?

Comment: quicker to write or quicker to execute?

Answer (score 6):

No. There are ways to code it quicker, but there are no shortcuts like you imply. Taken from [an answer I gave on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/test-if-any-fields-are-null/):

```
DECLARE @tb NVARCHAR(255), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @tb = N'dbo.[table]';

SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @tb + ' WHERE 1 = 0';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N' OR ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' IS NULL'
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tb);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Won't work in SQL Server 2005, but hopefully the OP will know what to do about it.

Comment: @Andriy Thanks. Corrected. I catch myself on that one all the time, sometimes I miss it. In this case I copied it from a question that was for 2008.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the column names using something like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = <table_name>
```

Then, I would write a procedure using this, and that would loop through the entries in your table and the column names.

Source: http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/337

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what quicker means.

If you mean quicker for SQL Server to execute, one thing you could do is write a trigger than updates a bit column that specifies if the entire row (other than the bit and primary key) are NULL. But, there should be a REAL good reason for this as it will impact your update performance. Indexes on those columns would help as well.

If you mean quicker to write, you could have SQL generate the where clause for you. But, unless you do this alot, it isn't worth the time in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Teaching-to-fish-instead-of-giving-you-the-fish kind of answer here:

One way of doing it is by creating a Stored Procedure that assembles and runs a dynamic query.

The Stored procedure will:

- have a Table name as input parameter.
- query the meta data system tables for the specific table structure.
- dynamically assemble a string (the actual query) with the `OR` statements for that table's columns.
- run the assembled query and return the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by doing case and sum like this. Here we are marking the 1 wherever we see a null and zero otherwise and then we are doing a sum for all the values

```
SELECT 
(case when (sum(case when id is null then 1 else 0 end)) > 0 then True else False end) as is_id_null,
(case when (sum(case when id is null then 1 else 0 end)) > 0 then True else False end) as is_name_null
from TABLE;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This could also help. It generates the script that lists the column name and the count of how many NULL values are in each of the columns in your table. Once you get the output, you'll have to copy or export it as a text and run it as a script.

```
DECLARE @tb VARCHAR(100) = '<schema>.<tableName>'

SELECT  'SELECT col_name = ''' + sys_cols.name + ''', null_count = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tb + ' WHERE ' + sys_cols.name + ' IS NULL;'
FROM sys.columns sys_cols
WHERE sys_cols.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('' + @tb + '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If any operation includes a null, the result is null, so create an operation that includes all columns and see if it's null.

If all columns are character type, concat them:

```
where column1 || column2 || column3 ... is null
```

Or if they are all numeric types:

```
where column1 + column2 + column3 ... is null
```

This approach is quick for the coder, but not so quick for the database.

Comment: Hello, seems to me that it is not too quick for the person who code also, what if you have to use this with a +50 columns table?

Comment: @FrancoGil if you have 50+ columns then you have 50+ values to check. There's no getting around have to code them, either manually, using code generation or building dynamic SQL in a stored procedure. Since it's a one-time task, and rare (I've never had to do something like this), I would just grab the create table code and edit it into the query.