# Updating whole Table where value in NULL [Without indication each column separately]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with updating whole table to 0[Zero], where value in NULL.
Without indication each column separately.

Comment: It can't be done. In order to use the SQL `UPDATE` statement, you **must** explicitly define which column(s) to set to `0` (instead of `NULL`)

Comment: What have you searched for?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705369/is-there-a-quick-way-to-check-if-any-column-is-null

Comment: Apologies to Larry Wall but, in this case, don't be lazy. Just spell out the columns and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, you just first have to extract all the column names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA or elsewhere, build the SQL into a string, then execute it:

```
USE MyDatabase
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100)
SELECT @TableName = 'MyTable'

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(4000) 
    SELECT @Sql = COALESCE(@Sql + '; ', '')
        + 'UPDATE dbo.'
        + @TableName
        + ' SET '
        + COLUMN_NAME
        + ' = 0 WHERE '
        + COLUMN_NAME
        + ' IS NULL'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
        AND DATA_TYPE NOT IN ('text','ntext','image')

SELECT @Sql
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Be sure to set `MyDatabase` and `MyTable` accordingly