# MySQL Is there a query to get all null occurrences in every column through a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, analytics, data-cleaning, workbench

Currently, I check null values in MySQL by running multiple
`SELECT * FROM tbl <field_name> IS NULL;`

This takes too much time especially if there many columns.

I wondered if there is a better way of checking all null values in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by :

```
select *
from table
where field_1 is null or field_2 is null ...;
```

An other way to do that is to get all columns using :

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns where TABLE_NAME = <table_name>
```

then create a procedure to loop through those columns

You can check this : [Is there a quick way to check if ANY column is NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705369/is-there-a-quick-way-to-check-if-any-column-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can speed your query is with indexing.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tbl.<field_name> IS NULL;
```

More info on NULL query optimization here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/is-null-optimization.html